# Ignoring items that have fewer than three words

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have a list of strings:

```
List1 = ['I am a man', 'I am a woman', 'I am', 'I', 'Ian']
```

How do I remove the items that have fewer than three words? The result should be:

```
['I am a man', 'I am a woman']
```

I tried using the `len` function but it wouldn't remove the list.

Comment: are words always separated by a space? Is `I'm` one word or two?

Comment: @meatsoace Yes, words are seperated by space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a list comprehension can filter your List1:

```
List2 = [i for i in List1 if len(i.split())>2]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
List2 = []
for sen in List1:
    if len(sen.split()) > 2:
        List2.append(sen)
```

Comment: you don't define `List2` before you use it and you're ignoring phrases with 3 words or less, but the OP wants to ignore phrases with *fewer* than three words